# Android TabHost with only selected tab on stack

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost with 4 tabs. I need only the selected tab activity to be available on the stack. When user changes the tab, how to finish the activity under previous tab. I tried the following code. Here showing code for first tab. It similar for remaining tabs:

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1", 
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_tab1))
                    .setContent(new Intent(this, Tab1.class)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

But the above code is deleting the Tab1 Activity on stack/heap only when the user comes again to that tab but not when user changes to new tab.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at this, what is your reason for this?
How do you know what's on the stack? Are you depending on onDestroy() or something?

I haven't got a full answer but you can see which tab is active:

Let your class implement *OnTabChangeListener*

```
 public class YourClass extends TabActivity  implements OnTabChangeListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Load all your normal objects as well as TabHost

// make your tabhost listen for tab changes
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

 @Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

   int currentTabNumber = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    for(int i=0;i<mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        if(i != currentTabNumber){
            System.out.println("I'm not a currently active tab");
        }           
    }

}

 }
```

Comment: I have main tab activity in which I have created 4 tabs each of which is a activity. In each activity I have put enter & exit logs in onCreate and onStop respectively. Through this I came to know that when I set the default current tab to 1, the first activity is entered. Again when user changes tab to 2,3 or 4, the corresponding activity gets started without any exit statement seen on first activity. When again 1st tab is pressed, now the first activity is getting finished and restarted newly.

Comment: If you want too see when a tab exits just override and use onPause(); :-)

Comment: overriding onPause or onDestroy is not working in a child activity. There should be a flag to implement this?